# How to se UIImagePickerController (Camera source) inside UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to set UIImagePickerController inside my UITabBarController but I want it to be from source: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera

How can I set this?

I added a controller to UITabBarController and set it as UIImagePickerController, but I cannot find a option to set it to be the Camera In Interface Builder. I just found PhotoLibrary and SavedPhotos.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Ignacio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to myself:
Is not possible since Camera source is not available in Mac OS, (same as simulator), hence not available in IB.
This has to be done programatically.
So:

- create UIImagePickerController with camera as the source
- add it into tabbarcontroller's controllers.

Probably i should not use UITabbarController but UITabBar instead. (So I can load controllers dinamically and show them modally.)